# Show $ g(s):=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)t^{s-1} dt$ is well defined and analytic.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

Let f be a real-valued function as following : for fixed $z \in \mathbb{C}$
$$f(t) = \sum_{a,b \in \mathbb{N} }e^{-\lvert az +b \rvert^2 t}$$

Let's define $$ g(s):=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)t^{s-1} dt$$

Then, show that $g(s)$ is a well-defined and analytic for all $s \in \mathbb{C}$ except $s=0, 1$

---

[ My attempt ]

First, I showed that $\int_{t_0}^{\infty}f(t)t^{s-1} dt$ is well-defined for $t_0 >0$.

We know that for each $a>0$ , $b>0$ $$ a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab $$

Therefore,  $$ \lvert az+b \rvert^2 = a^2\lvert z \rvert^2+b^2+2\text{Re}(z)ab \geq 2\lvert z \rvert ab+2\text{Re}(z)ab = (2\lvert z \rvert + 2\text{Re}(z)) ab =:k_1ab$$

so

$$f(t) = \sum_{a,b \in \mathbb{N}}e^{-\lvert az +b \rvert^2 t} \leq \sum_{a,b \in \mathbb{N} }e^{-k_1ab t}$$

Therefore, we can check that $f(t)t^{s-1}$ has rapidly decaying at $\infty$

However i'm stuck here. I can't prove the integral of $g$ is well defined at $0$ and analytic part.

How to prove this?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You should somewhere require that $z$ is not real, or else the series defining $f$ will not converge. Note in your calculations that $a,b$ may be negative!

Comment: you're right. there is some issue, i fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant for $t >0,\Im(z)\ne 0$ $$f(t) = \sum_{a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^2 }e^{-\lvert az +b \rvert^2 t}$$ for $\Re(s) >1$ $$g(s):=\int_{0}^{\infty}(f(t)-1)t^{s-1} dt$$ is analytic, and it
extends to a meromorphic function on $\Bbb{C}$ with two simple poles at $0,1$.

For $v\in R^2$ look at
$$F_{M,t}(v)= \sum_{n\in Z^2} e^{-\pi ((v+n)^\top M (v+n))t}=\sum_{n\in Z^2} e^{-\pi \| M^{1/2} (v+n)\|^2 t}, \qquad M=\pmatrix{|z|^2&\Im(z)\\ \Im(z)& 1}$$
So that $$f(t)=F_{M,t/\pi}(0)$$

$F_{M,t}$ is $Z^2$ periodic, it has a Fourier series $$F_{M,t}(v)= \sum_{k\in Z^2} c_{M,t}(k) e^{2i\pi k^\top v}$$ $$ c_{M,t}(k)=\iint_{R^2} e^{-\pi \| M^{1/2} v\|^2 t}e^{-2i\pi k^\top v}dv= |\det(M)|^{-1/2} t^{-1} e^{-\pi \| M^{-\top/2} k\|^2/ t}$$

ie. $$F_{M,t}(0)= |\det(M)|^{-1/2} t^{-1} F_{M^{-\top},1/t}(0)$$
whence as $t\to 0$ $$F_{M,t}(0)  = |\det(M)|^{-1/2} t^{-1}+O(e^{-r/t})$$ so that
$$\int_0^\infty (F_{M,t}(0)-1+1_{t<1}-|\det(M)|^{-1/2} t^{-1} 1_{t<1}) t^{s-1}dt$$ $$=\pi^{-s} g(s)+\frac1s-|\det(M)|^{-1/2} \frac1{s-1}$$ is entire.

Comment: Thank you but may I ask you something? I don't understand some facts, sorry.

 $$\text{1. why} \| M (n)\|^2 = \lvert az +b \rvert^2 ,\text{where} n=(a,b)$$

$$\text{2. why we get "i.e.} F_{M,t}(0)= |\det(M)|^{-1} t^{-1} F_{M^{-\top},1/t}(0)"$$
$$\text{and why this imply "whence as  } t\to 0 \;\; F_{M,t}(0)  = |\det(M)|^{-1} t^{-1}+O(e^{-r/t}) "$$

$$\text{3. why} "\int_0^\infty (F_{M,t}(0)-1+1_{t<1}-|\det(M)|^{-1} t^{-1} 1_{t<1}) t^{s-1}dt$$ 
$$=\pi^{-s} g(s)+\frac1s-|\det(M)|^{-1} \frac1{s-1} \text{is entire}." $$
$$\text{ means that $g(s)$ has a meromorphic continuation?}$$

Comment: I went too fast, it is $(a,b) M (a,b)^\top = |az+b|^2$ so had to replace many $M$ by $M^{1/2}$ (the matrix is definite positive so the $1/2$ makes sense and $\|M^{1/2}v\|^2$ is really a shorcut to $v^\top M v$)

Comment: As $t\to \infty$, $F_{M,t}(0) = 1+ $ exponential decay terms (ie. $1+O(e^{-2rt})$) so as $t\to 0$, $F_{M,t}(0)= |\det(M)|^{-1/2} t^{-1}+O(e^{-r/t})$

Comment: Thank you! I understand almost your answer. Then, first of all, I need to show that $g(s)$ is well defined. How can I show $(f(t)-1)t^{s-1}$ is integrable near $0$ ?

Comment: It is for $\Re(s) > 2$ from $|az+b|^2 \ge c( |a|+|b|)$ so $f(t)\le (1+2/(e^{ct}-1))^2=O(t^{-2})$ near $0$ and $f(t)-1 = O(e^{-ct} t^{-2})$ on $(0,\infty)$

Comment: How can I know $e^{-ct}t^{-2}$ is integrable near $0$? I think $t^a$ is integrable near $0$ if $a>-1$.

Comment: That's why I said $\Re(s)>2$

Comment: Now I did it. Thank you so much!